# How to make the following conclusion?

Tags: integration, stochastic-calculus

There is a statement as follow:

$E(|X_1(t)-X_2(t)|)\leq\int_0^t \kappa[E(|X_1(t)-X_2(t)|)]ds$, where $\kappa$ is a strictly increasing concave function such that $\kappa(0)=0$ and $\int_{0+}\kappa^{-1}(u)du=+\infty$. This can be proved that $E(|X_1(t)-X_2(t)|)=0$.

How can I make the conclusion? I suspect to use Gronwall Inequality but I do not find the one similar to this.

The statement appears on p.184 of Stochastic differential equations and diffusion processes by Ikeda and Watanabe. $X_i(t)$ should be one dimensional process.

Comment: if $k=0 $ than $E(|X_1(t)-X_2(t)|)=0$

Comment: @Akashaero : I suppose it's $\kappa(0) = 0$, but the OP needs to confirm that

Comment: Nothing stochastic in here. Once the typo is cleared, one is given some nonnegative function $u$ such that $$u(t)\leqslant\int_0^t\kappa(u(s))ds$$ for every nonnegative $t$ and one asks to show that $u(t)=0$ for every nonnegative $t$.

Comment: Yes. It is $\kappa(0)=0$ and Nothing is stochastic, but I do not know how to obtain the conclusion. Any hints?